# How to solve this console error

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress-theming

How can i solve this console error. I have been feeling trouble for some days. My item link 
http://dijungle.com/afrin2/

Please inspect and you'll able to get it.

Thanks

Comment: Post your error here for our convenience thx

Comment: This is the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: The error should contains the file name and corresponding line. Next time you can direct find which line has problems in it

Comment: Please check my solution, issue at line no. 16. use the code mentioned in solution

Answer (score 2):

Error occurred because of single quotes was close wrong on line number 15 in header.php

```
WebFontConfig['google'] = {
 families: ['Roboto:700,400',  ''Open+Sans+Condensed',+sans-serif;']
};
```

so replace code as below

```
WebFontConfig['google'] = {
 families: ['Roboto:700,400', 'Open+Sans+Condensed', 'sans-serif']
};
```

and also as per typekit document syntax need to change as below

```
WebFontConfig = {
 google: { families: ['Roboto:700,400', 'Open Sans Condensed', 'sans serif'] }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code at line no. 16 as below

```
WebFontConfig['google'] = {families: ['Roboto:700,400', ''Open+Sans+Condensed',+sans-serif;']};
```

by below code

```
WebFontConfig['google'] = {families: ['Roboto:700,400', 'Open+Sans+Condensed','+sans-serif;']};
```

Comment: This is my wordpress theme, where i can find this code?

Comment: There is comment on your page /* You can add more configuration options to webfontloader by previously defining the WebFontConfig with your options */ you can find WebFontConfig and update this code

Comment: I think it is in index page

Comment: No, It was problem in my redux framework config file.

Comment: Vindhyachal Kumar Thank you so much for your better effort. Really you very helpful. Your effort was very appreciate.